# How to listen keydown event on ExtJS Panel

Tags: javascript, events, extjs, panel, keydown

I want to listen keydown events on panel and accordingly do corresponding actions on SVG inside panel. But I dont know how to listen  keydown event on ExtJS Panel ?
Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no event listener in extjs for a keydown event on a panel. Look through the extjs docs they are very well documented

Comment: Try using Ext.util.KeyMap, set the target config to your panel's El

Comment: Tried using KeyMap , still its now working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this could be a way forward for you http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?182956-4.1-KeyMap-for-processing-a-form

Comment: `listeners: {
   render: function (p) {
    p.focus();
   p.el.dom.onkeydown = function (e) {
       // my code
    }
    }
   }`

This piece of code worked for me.
Anyways thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

In Ext4 you can add KeyMap on any editable component like this:

```
        var map = new Ext.util.KeyMap( Ext.getCmp('textfield').getEl(), [{
            key: [10,13],
            fn: function(ord, e){
                alert("Enter was pressed inside textfield");
            }
        }, {
            key: "abc",
            fn: function(){ alert('a, b or c was pressed'); }
        }
    ]);
```

If you want to listen keyboard events on a divs, don't forget to set an element focusable:

```
autoEl: { tabindex: 0 }.
```

Here is an KeyMap example for textfield, empty panel and on a window:

[textfield, panel, window KeyMap example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3pbq)